# regex character replacement with space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function that forces a space after every 26 letters

```
function nospaces(t)    
{
    if(t.value.match(/\S{27}/g))
    {    
        //alert('Sorry, you can not enter a word more than 26 characters long');
        t.value[5]=t.value.replace(/\S{27}/g,'');
    }
}
```

Now i want that every 27th letter that user enter instead of space should replaced by space

Comment: Do you really want to replace the 27th letter, or do you want a space to be inserted before it?

Comment: after every 26 letter means 27th character should be replaced with space if it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make smart use of regex groups, if `\S{26}` is followed by a `\S` replace the whole match with the first group followed by a space;

`var foo = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab'.replace(/(\S{26})(\S)/, '$1 ');`
gives:
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz b`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
var string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0hjh...'; 
// 0 is 27th
string = string.replace(/(\S{26})\S/g, '$1 ');
```

I'm not sure if this is the best practice, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nospaces(t)    
{
     return t.replace(/\S{27}(?=\S)/g, '$& ');
}
```

To replace sequence of 27 characters with a sequence of 27 characters followed by a space if that sequence is followed by a non-whitespace character.